# JavaScript RegEx excluding certain word/phrase?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a RegEx pattern to test if a string contains several substrings with the structure:

```
"cake.xxx"
```

where xxx is **anything but not** "cheese" or "milk" or "butter".

For example:

- `"I have a cake.honey and cake.egg"` should return `true`, but
- `"I have a cake.**milk** and cake.egg"` should return `false`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Is it this what you want?

```
^(?!.*cake\.(?:milk|butter)).*cake\.\w+.*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2usad)

this will match the complete row if it contains a "cake.XXX" but not when its "cake.milk" or "cake.butter"

`.*cake\.\w+.*` This part will match if there is a "cake." followed by at least one wrod character.

`(?!.*cake\.(?:milk|butter))` this is a negative lookahead, this will prevent matching if the string contains one of words you don't allow

`^` anchor the pattern to the start of the string

Comment: Thats just a non capturing group because of the `?:`. The only difference is that the matched string is NOT stored into a variable.

Comment: That means I can use (milk|butter) instead, right? And more, is this neccessary to put the "negative lookahead" rule right after the string-start mark "^" ?

Comment: Is this neccessary to put the "negative lookahead" rule right after the string-start mark "^" ?

Comment: Yes so it searches really the whole string otherwise it will match parts of "cake.milk" or the whole string. You can try this easy on the link I put in my answer, change the regex and you see what it will match.

Comment: You should check the link, I can not connect to that website? Anyway, you gave me the great answer. Thanks a lot.