# RegExp to match string that includes 'apple' but does not match 'orange' in same string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

Given the following data

```
green-pineapple-bird
red-apple-dog  
blue-apple-cat  
green-apple-orange-horse  
green-apple-mouse
```

I am trying to figure out how to get (Javascript) RegExp.test() to match for any entry that contains the word "apple" (anywhere) but not match any entry that contains the word "orange" (anywhere). The resulting list would be:

```
red-apple-dog  
blue-apple-cat  
green-apple-mouse
```

I have included the dashes in the data just to make it easier to read. The actual data may, or may not, include dashes.

If I try this:

```
/^(?!orange).*(apple).*/gm
```

using https://regex101.com/ it matches all lines.

Using [JavaScript RegEx excluding certain word/phrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674172/javascript-regex-excluding-certain-word-phrase) for inspiration I tried:

```
/^(?!.*apple\.(?:orange|butter)).*apple\.\w+.*/gm
```

If it makes a difference I am using Mozilla Rhino 1.7R4.

Comment: Here is non-regex: `if(str.includes('apple') && !str.includes('orange'))`

Comment: I think not bothering with regex is the right way to go, but that will catch pineapple as well. Better to `.split('-')` and check `.indexOf()` or `.includes()`.

Comment: I chose to go with RegExp because the queries are stored externally to the code and the code is meant to be general purpose, so anticipating all of the use cases and/or adding logic to distinguish indexOf vs RegExp would complicate things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each character *not* in `apple` (before *or* after), you need to repeat the negative lookahead for `orange`. Because you don't want `pineapple` to match, you should also put word boundaries around the `apple`:

```js
const re = /^((?!orange).)*\bapple\b((?!orange).)*$/;
`green-pineapple-bird
red-apple-dog  
blue-apple-cat  
green-apple-orange-horse  
green-apple-mouse`
  .split('\n')
  .forEach(str => {
    console.log(re.test(str) + ' ' + str)
  });
```